# Silverstripe: Set default values only once

Tags: php, silverstripe

Hi I am trying to set default values (once only) of an ArticlePage. Because it is some kind of a blogging system i use date and time for that. Date and time get integrated, but everytime i change and update the page, date and time changed too. Which means, the url changes. 
How can I modify populateDefaults to update only once?
Any chance with onBeforeWrite? 
Because the page should not be new anymore once saved, but it keeps changing
mille grazie *

ArticlePage.php

```
<?php
class ArticlePage extends Page {

    private static $db = array(
        'Place' => 'Text',
        'Date' => 'Date',
    );


    public function populateDefaults(){
        parent::populateDefaults();

        // set title and urlsegment only once ?
        $this->Title = _t('Page.TITLE', "post-" . date("Ymd-His"));
        $this->URLSegment = _t('Page.URLSEGMENT', "post-" . date("Ymd-His"));
    }

    public function onBeforeWrite(){
        parent::onBeforeWrite();
        if ($this->Status == 'New page'){ // <-- should not be new after saving once
            $this->populateDefaults();
            }
        if ($this->Verison == 0){
            $this->populateDefaults();
            }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to use the populateDefaults() function.

Silverstripe will automatically call it when the pages are created...

```
private static $db = array(
    'Place' => 'Text',
    'Date' => 'Date',
);


public function populateDefaults(){
    parent::populateDefaults();

    // set title and urlsegment only once ?
    $this->Title = _t('Page.TITLE', "post-" . date("Ymd-His"));
    $this->URLSegment = _t('Page.URLSEGMENT', "post-" . date("Ymd-His"));
}
```

}

Comment: problem is, if i leave onBeforeWrite away, only the Page.URLSEGMENT shows "post-date-time" the Page.TITLE shows "new Article Page" ...
and with the onBeforeWrite date and time always get updated

Comment: in other words, silverstripe calls populateDefaults on page creation and whenever the page is updated

Comment: As indicated above, populateDefaults() is the function you should use and it is called when you create a new one. If you want to do something each time it is saved, you can do it inside onBeforeWrite().

onBeforeWrite() has two usage: Create and Edit. 
If you save something onBeforeWrite() is called always. 
If ID exists, it means it is edit mode (record already exists, no new record is created now). 
You can check in this way: 
    if ($this->ID){  //if editing  

    }  else {  //if creating

    }

Comment: If we change the page type populateDefaults is called and overrides the existing content . How to avoid it?